# What happens if you cast Banishment on a Darklord in Ravenloft?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ravenloft

Playing in Ravenloft, if my Sorcerer tries to Banish one of the Darklords, what would happen?  I know the Campaign Guides say the Darklords will always be returned to their demiplanes, but will they even be allowed to leave their jails for a moment?

Comment: Are you attempting to banish Strahd from Barovia, or is this a homebrewed Darklord from a homebrewed realm, or what?

Comment: Azalin the Lich king, but I assume the rules would apply to all the Darklords in thier individual Domains.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Nothing

Using just the available D&D5E resources for Ravenloft, consult the section in Chapter Two of *Curse of Strahd* on [Alterations to Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/cos/the-lands-of-barovia#AlterationstoMagic) (emphasis added):

> The land of Barovia resides in its own demiplane, isolated from all other planes, including the Material Plane. No spell — not even wish — allows one to escape from Strahd’s domain. Astral projection, teleport, plane shift, and similar **spells cast for the purpose of leaving Barovia *simply fail*, as do effects that banish a creature to another plane of existence.**

While the passage is specific to Barovia, because that's where the adventure book is set, it worked the same way in previous editions for all the Domains of Dread. The Dark Powers decide who comes and who goes, and they would *never* let a mere mortal send a Dark Lord anywhere but his custom prison.

Answer (score 6):

### The spell functions as intended, for up to one minute.

If you were to cast Banishment on Strahd, or on another Darklord in their own domain, and they failed their save, they would be banished to a harmless demiplane for as long as the caster maintains concentration, up to 1 minute, then reappear in the closest unoccupied square, per normal rules for banishing a creature from its home plane. While it's indeed true that Chapter 2 specifies that spells cast to leave Barovia, or to banish a creature **to another plane of existence** simply fail, it also specifies the following:

> Magic that summons creatures or objects from other planes functions normally in Barovia, **as does magic that involves an extradimensional space.** Any spells cast within such an extradimensional space (such as that created by Mordenkainen’s magnificent mansion) are subject to the same restrictions as magic cast in Barovia.

When cast upon a creature in their own plane, Banishment sends the target to a "harmless demiplane".

According to Chapter 2 of the Dungeon Master's guide:

> **Demiplanes are extradimensional spaces** that come into being by a variety of means and boast their own physical laws. Some are created by spells. Others exist naturally, as folds of reality pinched off from the rest of the multiverse.

The spell's function becomes a little fuzzier when dealing with entities that do not count Barovia as their home plane. As those creatures, per Banishment's text, would normally be banished to their home plane, and so the spell fails outright. This leads to a very counterintuitive interpretation of the spell, where native creatures *can* be banished, all be it temporarily, whereas non-native creatures *cannot be banished at all*. For simplicity and fairness while maintaining the tone of Barovia, as DM my ruling would be for Banishment to treat all targets as native to Barovia.